# Reformat a text file to csv using bash script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, csv

I have a file (exOut.txt) consisting of several thousand lines of text in the following format:

```
[CV] solver=newton-cg, penalty=l2, multi_class=ovr, max_iter=187.637633813, C=0.778324314482
[CV] solver=newton-cg, penalty=l2, multi_class=ovr, max_iter=187.637633813, C=0.778324314482
[CV] solver=newton-cg, penalty=l2, multi_class=ovr, max_iter=187.637633813, C=0.778324314482
[CV] solver=sag, penalty=l2, multi_class=multinomial, max_iter=187.637633813, C=0.31181629405
[CV] solver=sag, penalty=l2, multi_class=multinomial, max_iter=187.637633813, C=0.31181629405
[CV] solver=sag, penalty=l2, multi_class=multinomial, max_iter=187.637633813, C=0.31181629405
[CV]  solver=sag, penalty=l2, multi_class=multinomial, max_iter=187.637633813, C=0.31181629405, score=0.497312, total=11.0min
[CV]  solver=sag, penalty=l2, multi_class=multinomial, max_iter=187.637633813, C=0.31181629405, score=0.499232, total=11.0min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-2)]: Done   2 out of   6 | elapsed: 11.0min remaining: 22.0min
[CV]  solver=sag, penalty=l2, multi_class=multinomial, max_iter=187.637633813, C=0.31181629405, score=0.499762, total=11.1min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-2)]: Done   3 out of   6 | elapsed: 11.1min remaining: 11.1min
[CV]  solver=newton-cg, penalty=l2, multi_class=ovr, max_iter=187.637633813, C=0.778324314482, score=0.449309, total=19.6min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-2)]: Done   4 out of   6 | elapsed: 19.6min remaining: 9.8min
[CV]  solver=newton-cg, penalty=l2, multi_class=ovr, max_iter=187.637633813, C=0.778324314482, score=0.449831, total=19.7min
[CV]  solver=newton-cg, penalty=l2, multi_class=ovr, max_iter=187.637633813, C=0.778324314482, score=0.451609, total=19.7min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-2)]: Done   6 out of   6 | elapsed: 19.7min remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-2)]: Done   6 out of   6 | elapsed: 19.7min finished
...
```

I am trying to write a shell script which will take this file and reformat it to create a new file in csv format, only recording the lines with a "score" attribute. This should look something like:

```
solver,penalty,multi_class,max_iter,C,score
sag,l2,multinomial,187.638,0.312,0.497
sag,l2,multinomial,187.638,0.312,0.499
sag,l2,multinomial,187.638,0.312,0.500
newton-cg,l2,ovr,187.638,0.779,0.449
newton-cg,l2,ovr,187.638,0.779,0.450
newton-cg,l2,ovr,187.638,0.779,0.450
```

Where all values are rounded to the nearest 1000th place, when possible.

And ultimately I would like to take this csv and make a condensed version by identifying records with all fields equal except "score", and replacing those with one record with an average score given those parameters. For example:

```
solver,penalty,multi_class,max_iter,C,avg_score
sag,l2,multinomial,187.638,0.312,0.499
newton-cg,l2,ovr,187.638,0.779,0.450
```

Any help is appreciated! I am not a pro at regular expressions which is mainly why I ask.

**EDIT 1** Thanks for the feedback, here's some more info:

Thus far I've tried various scripts using grep, awk and sed including, `grep '=.*,' exOut.txt` which only recognizes one large occurrence of the pattern rather than multiple fields, and `sed 's/^[^\=]*\=//g' exOutput.txt > firstCSV.csv` which only cleans up the first part of each line.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code writing service, where you post your requirements and language of choice and someone writes the code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we do expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first, and include your efforts in your question. Please [edit] to show the code you've attempted yourself before asking here. If you need more info, see [ask].

Comment: It should be pretty simple with `awk`.  Give it a try, and if you still cannot get it, you can post your code and an example of the output it's giving you.  (And `awk` is well worth the time to learn.)

Comment: If you want a bash script, why is this tagged with python?

Comment: The data file was generated by a python program using scikit-learn, so I thought that if anyone had created this type log file before they might have some ideas... but you're right, a python tag is probably confusing.

Answer (score 0):

1.The question you can reference the `parseRawDataFile` function.

2.the question you can reference thr `parseCsvDataFile`  function.

3.In the code had some hard code, please notice.

```
import codecs
datausage = r"e:\temp\111.txt"
storagePath = r"e:\temp\222.csv"
storagePath_New = r"e:\temp\222_New.csv"
strStr = "score"

def parseRawDataFile(path):
    sumResult = "solver,penalty,multi_class,max_iter,C,score\r\n"
    # [CV]  solver=sag, penalty=l2, multi_class=multinomial, max_iter=187.637633813, C=0.31181629405, score=0.497312, total=11.0min

    with open(path) as f:

        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if strStr in line:

                tempList = line.replace(",", "=").split("=")
                # print(tempList)
                sumResult += "%s,%s,%s,%.03f,%.03f,%.03f\r\n" % (tempList[1], tempList[3], tempList[5], float(tempList[7]), float(tempList[9]), float(tempList[11]))

    # print(sumResult)
    return sumResult

def parseCsvDataFile(path):
    sumResult = "solver,penalty,multi_class,max_iter,C,score\r\n"
    # sag,l2,multinomial,187.638,0.312,0.497

    nameList = []
    with open(path) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        temptSum = 0.0
        tempNum = 0
        for line in lines:
            if "solver" in line:
                continue
            tempList = line.split(",")
            if tempList[0] not in nameList:
                if temptSum != 0:
                    sumResult += "%.03f\r\n" % (temptSum/tempNum)
                sumResult += "%s,%s,%s,%.03f,%.03f," % (tempList[0], tempList[1], tempList[2], float(tempList[3]), float(tempList[4]))

                tempNum = 0
                temptSum = 0.0
                nameList.append(tempList[0])
            if tempList[0] in nameList:
                tempNum += 1
                temptSum += float(tempList[-1])

        sumResult += "%.03f\r\n" % (temptSum / tempNum)
    print(sumResult)
    return sumResult

def writeLog(f, d):
    try:
        f = codecs.open(f, 'w', 'utf-8')
        f.write(d)
        f.close()
    except:
        print("file is not exist.")

result = parseRawDataFile(datausage)
writeLog(storagePath, result)
result = parseCsvDataFile(storagePath)
writeLog(storagePath_New, result)
```